# Is it possible to pass data from DelegatingHandler to Controller in ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm implementing an authorization related DelegatingHandler where I load-up the api user (caller) profile from database. When the authorization is successful I'd like to pass this instance to the controller otherwise I'd must load it again.

Is there any way to do this without using session or rely on repository cache?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The HttpRequestMessage class contains a dictionary "Properties" that you could use to store that information. However, I am not sure if it is get persisted between the handler invocation and the controller action. Otherwise, you can try with an action filter where the action context is already created. The action context gives you access to the action arguments, where you can add an additional argument to be passed to the action.

Comment: Yes, the properties collection stays around for the entire lifecycle of the request.

Comment: Any way to do this and keep model binding ?

Answer (score 0):

In net6, the Properties Collection is deprecated. You should use [Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.options?view=net-6.0) instead. This post may interest you: [How to migrate from HttpRequestMessage.Properties to HttpRequestMessage.Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68270954/how-to-migrate-from-httprequestmessage-properties-to-httprequestmessage-options)