# How to migrate from HttpRequestMessage.Properties to HttpRequestMessage.Options

Tags: c#, .net-5

After upgrading to net5 I'm getting obsoletion warning:
`[CS0618] 'HttpRequestMessage.Properties' is obsolete: 'Use Options instead.'`
however there seems to be no migration guide.

I.e. there's following code

```
httpRequestMessage.Properties.Add(Key, Value);
```

How exactly it should be migrated? Is

```
httpRequestMessage.Options.Set(new HttpRequestOptionsKey<TValue>(Key), Value);
```

correct?

Comment: The `Options` property, of type `HttpRequestOptions`, is an `IDictionary<string, object>`, as the `Properties` property...

Comment: ... so, e.g., `httpRequestMessage.Options.Set<string>(new HttpRequestOptionsKey<string>("100"), "10");`, `httpRequestMessage.Options.Set<float>(new HttpRequestOptionsKey<float>("100"), 10.0f);` etc.

Comment: But this dictionary is private, so you cannot use it like dictionary. For some reason the added this weird api with HtppRequestOptionsKey and I want to know why they did so.

Comment: [Issue 34168 - Configuring request options in Browser WebAssembly](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/34168)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I struggled with the same thing and I found the solution.
Here is how you should use the new Options property.

Instead of `request.Properties.Add("foo", true);`
Write: `request.Options.Set(new HttpRequestOptionsKey<bool>("foo"), true);`

To read the key from response:
`response.RequestMessage.Options.TryGetValue(new HttpRequestOptionsKey<bool>("foo"), out bool foo);`

To be honest, I don't know why they changed it. It's strange we need to create a new HttpRequestOptionsKey object for each property. But it is what it is.

Comment: You can see in issue linked by Jimi that it's related to browser and webassembly. I just don't understand why they didn't add extension method which would handle it.

Answer (score -1):

You could switch on type - here's an example from attempting to clone an existing message:

```
foreach (var opt in httpRequestMessage.Options)
{
    switch (opt.Value)
    {
        case string s:
            clone.Options.Set<string>(new HttpRequestOptionsKey<string>(opt.Key), s);
            break;
        default:
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Can't deal with non-string message options ... yet.");    
    }
}
```

Comment: This is question about how to migrate code from obsoleted api, rather than copy options between cloned messages.

Comment: This code is useful for migration as well