# How to change code from HttpRequestMessage.Properties to HttpRequestMessage.Options

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I am working on upgrading a project to .NET 6 and in the unit tests I am getting a warning about properties being obsolete

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://localhost");
request.Properties[System.Web.Http.Hosting.HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey] = new HttpConfiguration();
```

I'm not sure what's the best way of changing properties to options in this instance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to migrate from HttpRequestMessage.Properties to HttpRequestMessage.Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68270954/how-to-migrate-from-httprequestmessage-properties-to-httprequestmessage-options)